# Determine regression model

Tags: regression

The relationship between my independent variable (on the x-axis) and the dependent variable (on the y-axis) looks like this. (Pearson correlation: 0.21 | Spearman correlation: 0.37)

[image]

My goal is to determine how many units of my IV are needed to reach some value X of my DV. To do that, I wanted to perform a regression so that I get the slope and the intercept which, in turn, allows me to plug in some value into the resulting function.

My question is how can I determine the best regression model for that kind of relationship? Or, to take one step back, is a regression even suitable for my problem?

Edit: The independent variable can also be expressed as a proportion

Comment: It looks like there may be a couple of points in the lower-left and upper-right part of graph which are pushing the line to have a slope. I would try with quantile regression to see if the median is also sloped.

Comment: how would that help me?

Comment: It would show whether you have some influential points which are skewing the slope. Or rather what kind of result you would get while diminishing their influence.

Comment: There are no influential points here.  Although the graphic does not make it possible to estimate how much data are shown, clearly the number is in the high hundreds to many thousands (or even more).  The line of course exhibits regression to the mean--but that should not be attributed to the three higher-leverage points at the right.  If you could make a more accurate scatterplot (use transparency, sunflower plots, or whatever) then it might be possible to suggest improvements to the fit that is shown.

Comment: It is a lot of overplotting in the plot, making it difficult to interprete. Can you make a better plot, maybe using smaller symbols, or alpha < 1 ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is all over the place. I can't really think of an appropriate regression model here. Maybe linear regression is still the best even though R squared will likely be very low

Comment: "All over the place" does not necessarily imply regression is inappropriate or useless.  There are enough data here that if the usual regression assumptions apply, the fit very well could be significant and, because it is nonzero, it could be useful.