# How to find optimization function

Tags: regression, optimization

Let's say I have a click through rate (%) as my independent variable and profit as my dependent variable. I have a dataset of 5,000 observations.

I would like to get a function, i.e. slope and intercept, that allows me to put in a click through rate (e.g. 5%) to see how much profit I would earn based on that.

How can I get that function?

Edit: The relationship of my data looks like that (x-axis is %)
[image]

Comment: google linear regression and your preferred tool [excel/google sheets etc]

Comment: Thanks, I edited the initial request because my data doesn't have a linear relationship -- which regression model could be an alternative here?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591743/determine-regression-model?

Comment: Wasn't sure if regression is the right technique to use + this time the x-axis is a proportion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine regression model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591743/determine-regression-model)